# Is it possible to save a mp3 file downloaded from server without converting it to ByteArray? (AS3)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, download, mp3

After searching around the net, I couldn't find a method to download a mp3 from a server, save it in the local storage (iPad) and then load and play it other than converting it to byteArray, saving it as .mp3 and then load it and read it back to mp3 to be able to play it in the flash application.

The problem is, although this method works fine, the uncompressed files (in byteArray format) saved in the local storage are too heavy and I suspect that the app is wasting memory.

My question is, is there any form of saving the mp3 directly, without any conversion, like a properly playable mp3? I can't use methods like download() or save() from FileReference.

Lots of thanks!!

Comment: Are you using Adobe AIR?

Comment: Yes I am @DodgerThud !!

Comment: Then look into [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) and [Working with File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7dc8.html). FileReference is for Flash Web and has fewer capabilities.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you mean by conversion and uncompressed. The byte array of a downloaded mp3 will contain the exact bytes the mp3 has. There is no uncompression taking place. The issue, more likely, is that you have multiple Bytearrays active at the same time.

Comment: The original mp3 files I am downloading don't have the same amount of bytes than the byteArrays I extract from them. I am using the method extract from Sound class, and the result files are much heavier...

Comment: I have already looked into File but I can't find out how it can help me. It haven't got methods to save files different from FileReference. It has many method to read files, but they have to be previously saved. Maybe I am misunderstanding something...

Comment: No it's not possible since the only way to save it is to use FileStream. I build a similar system but only for Android. If sound is not available locally, the code go play it from a server. In the meantime I load that same sound using URLLoader (binary) then save it locally using FileStream.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that... thanks!! @BotMaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION!! (WORKING PERFECTLY):

I continued looking for a method to do it around the net, and some forums gave me a clue to do whick I was searching. It was finally pretty simple, but I spent almost 2 weeks to find it out... here is my code:

```
var queue:LoaderMax = new LoaderMax({name:"mainQueue", onProgress:progressHandler, onComplete:completeHandler, onError:errorHandler});

queue.append( new DataLoader("http://" + **url**, {name:**"example.mp3"**format:"binay"}));
queue.load();

// Complete Event:
private function completeHandler():void {
        var file:File = new File(**your location**);    // appData
        var fr:FileStream = new FileStream();
        fr.open(file.resolvePath(nameIn), FileMode.WRITE);
        fr.writeObject(LoaderMax.getContent("example.mp3"));
        fr.close();
        fr = null;
        // Now the mp3 is saved in local storage, we load it as Sound object so we can play it.
        var loader:MP3Loader;
        loader = new MP3Loader(**your location**, {autoPlay:false}) ;
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function():Sound {
            loader.content.play(); // This line is the only one not checked, but I am completely sure you can do something like this to play the sound. For example, I introduce the loader.content in a Array of Sound and later I am capable to play any sound I want.
            loader.dispose(true);  // This is very important to free memory. You should do the same thing with queue when all items are downloaded.
        });
        loader.load();
}
```

I expect this help a lot of people!!